# jpa - can not generate entities from table in eclipse with foreign key (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, jpa, entities

I can not generate entities from table in eclipse with foreign key. I am usingsql server. Here a schema of my tables:[image]

There's a foreigne key between Pointage.Id and Pause.IdPointage. The geration fails when I try to generate the two tables. Pointage is generated but not Pause. In le last screen of generation Pause Table look empty (no column). It also fails when i just import Pause but it works well when I delete the foreign key.

I can see error in workspace log:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getImportStatements' in  class org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pause.FK_Pause_Pointage - mismatched sizes: 0 vs. 1 @ main.java.vm[7,9]
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:205)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:203)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:294)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:318)
at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:254)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:508)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateJavaFile(PackageGenerator.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateClass(PackageGenerator.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateInternal(PackageGenerator.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.doGenerate(PackageGenerator.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generate(PackageGenerator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.wizards.gen.GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard$GenerateEntitiesJob.runInWorkspace(GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard.java:285)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pause.FK_Pause_Pointage - mismatched sizes: 0 vs. 1
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPForeignKeyWrapper.buildColumnPairArray(DTPForeignKeyWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPForeignKeyWrapper.getColumnPairArray(DTPForeignKeyWrapper.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPForeignKeyWrapper.getLocalColumnPairs(DTPForeignKeyWrapper.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPForeignKeyWrapper.getBaseColumns(DTPForeignKeyWrapper.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPForeignKeyWrapper.baseColumnsContains(DTPForeignKeyWrapper.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPTableWrapper.foreignKeyBaseColumnsContains(DTPTableWrapper.java:216)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.isPartOfForeignKey(DTPColumnWrapper.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenColumn.isForeignKey(ORMGenColumn.java:266)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.buildColumnTypesMap(ORMGenTable.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.getImportStatements(ORMGenTable.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:137)
at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:350)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:180)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of rights with the database. I did not restart the database connection in eclipse after giving more rights to the user. After doing this, all was right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Eclipse Dali (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281991), which is the result of a bug in Eclipse DTP (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282206). There has been some recent development activity in DTP, after several years of nearly complete *in*activity; so, maybe if you add your vote to the latter bug, it might get fixed. :-)